# Why does this workaround for magic Perl internal variable work?

Tags: perl, debugging

#### t2.pl

```
1;
2;
3;
```

#### t.pl

```
package DB;

sub DB {
    print "HERE";

    our(undef, $f, undef) =  caller;

    # This does not work
    # my $ref =  \%{ "main::_<$f" };
    # $ref->{ 3 } =  {};

    # This does not work
    # *x =  $main::{ "_<$f" };
    # $x{ 3 } =  {};

    *dbline =  $main::{ "_<$f" };
    $dbline{ 3 } =  {};

    $DB::single =  0;
}

1;
```

```
PERL5DB="BEGIN{ require 't.pl' }" perl -d t2.pl
```

When you run this code you get `HEREHERE`, but the magic Perl variable has no effect when you do not alias it using `*dbline`.

So when you change first two examples to look like:

```
*dbline =  $main::{ "_<$f" }; # <<<<<<<<< With this it works!!!!
*x =  $main::{ "_<$f" };
$x{ 3 } =  { };
```

the breakpoint starts to work. (This is applied to Perl 5.14.4)

Why does it work in such way?

[DOC](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.2/perldebguts.html#Debugger-Internals)

Comment: All three work starting with 5.20, and so do `${ "main::_<$f" }{3} = {};` and `${ *{ $main::{ "_<$f" } } }{3} = {};`.

Comment: Looks like a bug. I can reproduce the issue in 5.16.3, but not in 5.22.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been [reported](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=119799) before:

> perldebguts says:
>
> - Each hash `%{"_<$filename"}` contains breakpoints and actions keyed by line number. Individual entries (as opposed to the whole hash) are settable.
>
> This implies that breakpoints set on `%{"_<..."}` apply to the named file. That is not actually true, as every `%{"_<..."}` hash sets breakpoints on lines in `@DB::dbline`, regardless of which file it refers to. The assumption is that debuggers will alias `*DB::dbline` to `*{"_<..."}` before setting any breakpoints.
>
> Hence, all `%{"_<..."}` hashes are the same.
>
> Is this a case where the documentation should be expanded to match the implementation? Or should we change the implementation to make each `%{"_<..."}` hash work on its corresponding `@{"_<..."}` array? The latter seems more useful to me.

In 5.20.0, the behavior was [changed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#Perl-5-Debugger-and--d) so that you don't have to alias `@DB::dbline`:

```
$ PERL5DB='
  sub DB::DB {
      ($p,$f,$l) = caller;
      print "$f:$l\n";
      ${"::_<$f"}{3} = 1; # no need for alias
      $DB::single = 0
  }
' perl -d foo
foo:1
foo:3
```